# What will be the best practice to re-start GeoCoordinateWatcher when it fails to get current LatLon

Tags: windows-phone-7

Declare a  GeoCoordinateWatcher tracker. This tracker will start on PageOnload event as below.

I dont know how to create a condition such that it will  show this :case GeoPositionStatus.NoData, So  I need some advise. My objective is it will re-start until it gets the current Latitude and longitude.

Q1) for  case GeoPositionStatus.NoData, what will be the best practice to re-start the GeoCoordinateWatcher?

Do this in case GeoPositionStatus.NoData

tracker.Stop();
 tracker.Start();

```
   void tracker_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      switch (e.Status)
       {
            case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:

            if (tracker.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Denied)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("The location Service on this device is off.Please read privacy.");
              }
            else
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Location service is working but it can not get location data.");
               }
              break;

           case GeoPositionStatus.Initializing:

              // Code which needs to be initialized goes here
                break;

            case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:

               //MessageBox.Show("Location data is not available.");

               break;

               case GeoPositionStatus.Ready:
                    // Code which needs to be executed when location data is available goes here
                    break;
            }
        }
```